# Figure number wrong

Tags: floats, numbering

I know this has been asked a lot, and I've browsed all possible answers, but none help. This is my code:

```
\documentsclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering 
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
\caption{Lipsum}
\label{fig:saussure} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}`
```

This is the first (and only figure) of my paper. However, in the text, the figure number is not `1` but `2.1` (section in which it appears).
I have made sure that the label is after the caption. I've even tried out putting the label inside the caption, or putting the caption at the top and the label at the end. Nothing works and the figure number remains the section number. How can I change this??

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which document class do you use? In all likelihood, your document class has a setting that numbers floats (figures and tables) within sections.

Comment: oh, forgot to add that. I use \documentclass{article}. And this is the first time I have problems with it.

Comment: That is odd, then. Can you provide a [full MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) so we can find out who it is that changes the number format?

Comment: it's best to add code to the question (where it can be formatted) not comments, I'll do it this time

Comment: I get **Figure 1:** from the posted example.

Comment: then there must be something else that influences that. Is there a way to redefine the figure numbering manually?

Comment: If the wrong numbering occurs in your actual document, start with a copy of that, and remove piece by piece until you're left with the smallest sample that replicates the problem. Then update your question with this new code.

Comment: @Lawell: Do you have something like `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{...}` in your code? If not, please post your code here to your question above.

Comment: I've updated the code. Could it be that the problem lies within the '\numberswithin' command?

Answer (score 3):

As you hint at yourself, the line

```
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
```

means that figures are numbered per section, so the output you're seeing is in fact exactly what you have told LaTeX to do. Anyway, getting continous numbering of figures is of course just a matter of deleting that line.